# ChatGPT neovim plugin installed, but will not load

Tags: plugins, configuration, lunarvim

I'm having difficulty using this new ChatGPT plugin. By executing packer status, I see it's installed, but isn't loading. Additionally, nui.nvim is not loading either. Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Here's the config file:

```
-- install ChatGPT
print("ChatGPT load begins.")
table.insert(lvim.plugins, {
  "jackMort/ChatGPT.nvim",
  opt = true,
  keys = { "<leader>gpt" },
  module_pattern = { "chatgpt*" },
  after = { "nui.nvim", "telescope.nvim" },
  setup = function()
    print("ChatGPT getting pw.")

    -- API key command to retrieve the ChatGPT API key
    api_key_cmd = "op read op://private/LVIM_Credential/credential --no-newline"
    print("ChatGPT plugin setup executed!")
  end,
  config = function()
    require("user.plugins.chatgpt").setup()
  end,
  requires = {
    "MunifTanjim/nui.nvim",
    "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
    "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim"
  }
})
print("ChatGPT load ends.")

-- Additional Plugins
table.insert(lvim.plugins, {
  "ChristianChiarulli/swenv.nvim",
  "KeitaNakamura/tex-conceal.vim",
  "SirVer/ultisnips",
  "christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator",
  "kdheepak/cmp-latex-symbols",
  "lervag/vimtex",
  "mfussenegger/nvim-dap-python",
  "nvim-neotest/neotest",
  "nvim-neotest/neotest-python",
  "p00f/clangd_extensions.nvim",
  "stevearc/dressing.nvim",
  --use
  ({
    "MunifTanjim/nui.nvim",
    module = { "nui.layout", "nui.popup" },
    module_pattern = { "nui.*" }
  }),
})
```

I've added a few debug print statements, and they come out as expected. The complete file may be seen at:  https://github.com/56phil/lvim_config.git